# trouble deploying angular 8 frontend with php backend to bluehost VPS getting 404 error from API and 404 on reload of non index pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, angular8

I built and angular 8 app with a php backend ( 7.3 ). I am trying to launch my site on bluehost. I set up the database ( MySql ), set the password, username etc. I put my folders in the public_html folder. Index.html loads but throws up a 404 for the api. Additionally, when I nav to another page then refresh, I also get a 404 error. Folder structure looks like:

public_html/
( config.ini & htaccess & api_folder & index.html )

The spa_folder has the index.html

I tried a lot of solutions for the htaccess but nothing seems to be working. Whatever I try I get the 404 error on console for the API but the index page loads.

I'm just kinda stuck and not sure where to investigate for a solution. Any help or ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering, my .htaccess paths were slightly off and the issue was corrected in the .htaccess.